# Bootstrap tagsinput is not displaying data from (Controller) Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap tags input field in HTML as below :

```
input type="text" name="panel" ng-model="requirement.panel"  data-role="tagsinput"
```

My Controller Model Value is as below:

```
{"_id":"58c6a81d90a4cc1a8801b110","panel":["sdaaaaaaaaaa,daaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,adaaaaaaaaaad"]}
```

But my Panel is always empty and showing no values. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panel is an array, you must access it using the index

```
input type="text" name="panel" ng-model="panel[0]" data-role="tagsinput"
```

Comment: edited. Requirement object does not exist right? share your controller pls

Comment: what is returned from the request? data is {"panel":["sdaaaaaaaaaa,daaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,adaaaaaaaaaad"]}?

Comment: Response from browser is oly an empty panel box when i remove data-role="tagsinput" from html i can view the values but when i add it i could not see anything

Comment: you must use http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/, data binding does not work in bootstrap tagsinput plugin, or you can create a directive to handle data binding within the plugin